# Good php API for extracting country code from IP?

Tags: php, geolocation, ip

I'm wondering has anyone had any experience in doing a whois on an IP and extracting the country code from that IP? Wondering what api would be the cleanest way of doing this with php.

Comment: retagged, you're looking for geolocation, not whois.  Useful question though so +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the [MaxMind GeoIP database](http://www.maxmind.com/). They have a [PHP API](http://www.maxmind.com/app/php).

Answer (score 1):

You can use my service, the http://ipinfo.io API for this:

Assuming you want all of the details, you can use PHP's json_decode to parse the response:

```
function ip_details($ip) {
    $json = file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/{$ip}");
    $details = json_decode($json);
    return $details;
}

$details = ip_details("8.8.8.8");

echo $details->city;     // => Mountain View
echo $details->country;  // => US
echo $details->org;      // => AS15169 Google Inc.
echo $details->hostname; // => google-public-dns-a.google.com
```

JSONP is also supported, so you can call the API from javascript:

```
$.get("http://ipinfo.io", function(response) {
    console.log(response.city);
}, "jsonp");
```

More details are available at http://ipinfo.io/developers