# Currency list for php and to show the currency symbol

Tags: php

I need a list all currency and I would like to register a user by tagging his currency. So when he logs in his currency symbol will appear? Is there any mechanism available in php?

Answer (score 4):

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741347/how-to-get-country-code-and-currency-code-by-ip-address) shows how to get currency code using IP. Once you get the currency code you can search for a symbol with a simple SELECT statement. This means you will need a table with [currency codes and symbols](http://tools.currenciesdirect.net/world-currencies/) stored. You will need to have a basic unserstanding of the Zend Framework to use this solution.

If you are asking the user for their country information, then you will not need to extract the IP. If you're taking this route, then a simple SELECT statement will do the trick:

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("example.com", "user", "password", "database");

//assuming the form with their country information has posted from a select box
$countryISO = $_POST['country'];

//select the currency symbol with the country code
$sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT curr_symbol FROM tablename WHERE iso3 = '$countryISO'");

//fetch the result
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);
?>
```

Then you can store or display the information about the user. And, as always, anytime you are connecting to a database be cautious that you are not [vulnerable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: +1 for the comment but use mysqli opp instead and `mysql_fetch_assoc` should be `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` or `$mysql->fetch_assoc` as the case may be

Answer (score 0):

I used [Bootstrap Form Helpers](http://www.freenetmall.com/common/jquery/FormHelpers/docs/currency.html).

1. Let the user choose a currency using the BFH Currency select box.
2. Save the Currency Code in the data-base.
3. Load the selected currency in anyplace you like using the BFH Currency span.

See the examples in [BFH](http://www.freenetmall.com/common/jquery/FormHelpers/docs/currency.html) for more details.

If you do not like to use the BFH you can get the currency arrays in the next links:

1. [Currency List](https://gist.github.com/Min2liz/5728013)
2. [Currency Symbols](https://gist.github.com/Gibbs/3920259)

Build a Select Box using the $currencyList array, the option value need to be the currency code, when you like to show the symbol you can use the currency symbols array with the same currency code, e.g. $currencySymbols[$currencyCode].