# android get country name from Ip address

Tags: android, ip, country

I'm now developing any Android App.
I want to add function to get country name from current IP.
How I can implement it?
I tried to find the way for serveral days, but couldn't find the way.
Please help me.
Thank you very much.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting country code with the help of device IP address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17475232/getting-country-code-with-the-help-of-device-ip-address)

Comment: This is interesting because the internet founders have ordered the ip addresses by language.