# Getting Currency Information From Country Code in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, geolocation, ip

I want to get the currency code information (for example:USD etc.) from country code.I tried most of methods but I cannot have this data.I had the country code from geolocation.
How can I solve this problem and get the currency code?

Comment: Here is the data: http://country.io/currency.json

Comment: see this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741347/how-to-get-country-code-and-currency-code-by-ip-address

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do with this following api its very easy and good

https://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/alpha/in
"in" be the country code for india.

Eg with jquery

```
jQuery.getJSON(
"https://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/alpha/in,
   function (data) {
    console.log(data.currencies)
     }
);
```

in data: you get almost every information related to country

Comment: Unfortunately this answer has aged out. restcountries now redirects to a service which is not free, or at least, you cannot get currency data for free anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Copy the object in this [page](http://country.io/currency.json) into your code, like this

```
var countryCurrencies = {
    "BD": "BDT",
    "BE": "EUR",
    "BF": "XOF",
    ...
    "UA": "UAH",
    "QA": "QAR",
    "MZ": "MZN"
}
//get your country code
var countryCode = "ma"; //For example
var currency = countryCurrencies.hasOwnProperty(countryCode.toUpperCase()) ? countryCurrencies[countryCode.toUpperCase()] : "Unkonw";


//The result : curreny = "MAD"
```

Comment: This is a more optimized answer. The currency code does not change very frequently. It is better in term of performance to embed the table into code than remote method.

Answer (score 1):

Here an Array with all Country Information:

```
<?php $location = unserialize(file_get_contents('http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip='.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])); print_r($location) ?>
```